# Object as Class variable in child class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, inheritance

I have a class with an options variable like this:

```js
export class ParentComponent extends GrandParentComponent {
  options = {
    autoScale: true,
    showLegend: true,
    showTimeline: true,
    autoRefresh: true,
    timeRange: {
      timeFrom: -2592000000,
      timeTo: 0
    }
  };

  constructor(){}

  methodNeedingThoseOptions(){
     this.overloadedMethod(this.options.timeRange.timeFrom, this.options.timeRange.timeTo);
  }

  overloadedMethod(timeFrom, timeTo){
    service.method1(timeFrom, timeTo)
  }

}
```

and I also have a child class which extends that class

```js
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  options = {
    autoScale: true,
    showLegend: true,
    showTimeline: true,
    autoRefresh: true,
    timeRange: {
      timeFrom: -604800000,
      timeTo: 0
    }
  };

  overloadedMethod(timeFrom, timeTo){
    console.log(timeFrom);
    service.method2(timeFrom, timeTo)
  }

}
```

I've tried using a getter, and some other ways but I can't figure out how to make the child options be used instead of the parents. I haven't been able to find any examples where a Class variable is a object so I'm guessing this is the issue but I don't know why this shouldn't work.

Comment: What makes you think the child options are not used? Please provide a [mcve] complete with the calls to your methods.

Comment: I see no JSON involved here. JSON is a text format, like CSV or XML

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=46&pc=78#

Comment: I tried and working for me.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=30#code/MYGwhgzhAEAK0G8BQ1XQPYAcAuBLdAdjALyIpoUFgC2ApgFzQBEAyrgE5gBWTANORVRgA5g2gAmAKwDoAXyTykoSDADC0WgA9stAgBMY8ZBSx5CJMoLRU6jJgGkwnAnxkURY8QDYZ8xcHN0EFoAOhB0YQAKSIJaAHdoVQBKENN8IiSAbiA

Comment: As others have noted, this works fine in isolation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6ntveb?embed=1&file=index.ts. Sounds like there must be something else going on that is not shown in your question.

Comment: Yea I just tried it there as well and it works as expected. Must be related to our angular setup. We are using ComponentFactoryResolver to inject these components to the host view. the setup is as above and my console.log shows that its logging from the child component but it's still the parent components value.

Comment: Try to reproduce it in Stackblitz.

Comment: Working on isolating the involved classes/methods for a stackblitz